# What are the difficulties in making e-beam lithography common?

Tags: chip-design, lithography

3D printers are common and *cheap*. An e-beam lithographer doesn't seem much more difficult; laying down the photoresist seems pretty similar, and drawing lines with an e-beam doesn't seem very hard. Why are e-beam lithographers not as commonplace as 3D printers?

Comment: Needing to be done in a vacuum probably doesn't help. And 3D printing is extremely versatile, unlike lithography?

Comment: What is the use case for home electron beam lithography?  It's very precise but is slow, expensive, requires chemicals, vacuum, and probably will take up most of a room all to make microscopic grooves in something.

Comment: They might be on export control lists such as [Implementation of Additional Export Controls: Certain Advanced Computing and Semiconductor Manufacturing Items; Supercomputer and Semiconductor End Use; Entity List Modification](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2022-21658/p-381) or [UK Strategic Export Control List](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/64ef1c7e13ae15000d6e305f/uk-strategic-export-control-lists.pdf), this limiting their availability. Those example export control lists seem to control certain feature sizes, and the question doesn't specify a target feature size.

Comment: To actually use e-beam lithography (or any other kind of microlithography) to do anything useful in semiconductors you'd also need a ton of other equipment and some nasty, toxic and hard to source chemicals (HF acid, silane etc.) for etching and doping as well as developing and cleaning. I can't imagine there would be much market for it, even if it could be made for under $10,000. There are a very few people such as Sam Zeloof mucking about with making crude ICs in their basement or garage, but very few attempt let alone are as successful as Sam.

Comment: e-beam lithography does not build up anything, once done (exposing the resist) in goes to next step selectively removing (etching)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ins not about electrical circuits

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is the expense, you need a cleanroom (expensive) and also somebody to handle the materials and chemicals. Electron beams are expensive (microscopes are commonly 100k+) in their own way as you need carefully calibrated equipment. So most hobbyists can't afford the cost.

It's the time it takes to actually 'write' the pattern on the wafer:

> To cover the 700 cm2 surface area of a 300 mm silicon wafer, the
> minimum write time would extend to 7*108 seconds, about 22 years. This
> is a factor of about 10 million times slower than current optical
> lithography tools. It is clear that throughput is a serious limitation
> for electron beam lithography, especially when writing dense patterns
> over a large area.
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron-beam_lithography

This restricts the tech to those who can wait.

[Cannons nanoimprint](https://global.canon/en/technology/nil-2023.html) lithography offers a simmilar thing to 3D printing but it's more of a stamp process.

Comment: But you don't want to write a whole 300mm / 70000mm^2 wafer. If it's for prototyping, you just want to write one chip - a few mm^2. You don't mass-manufacture complex PCBs on a robotic mill, either - the point of having one is so you can manufacture *any PCBs at all* on your desk within minutes or at least an hour.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly my point...

Comment: But it's not a point. 3D printers also take hours to make a part, and they're still popular.

Comment: I added costs reasons to the question

Comment: FDM manufacturing also used to cost $100k+ until the advent of no-corners-uncut plastic 3D printers. So I don't think that's a good reason either. Some people built electron microscopes in their garage for much less than $1k. Obviously they aren't as good as the professional ones - just like 3D printers.

Comment: You can build a 3d printer in the sub 100$ range, which is about as much as vacuum systems cost at minimum. You need a nice vacuum system that will do better than 10e-5 torr so that gets expensive. you'd need that, the electron microscope and the materials and the know how to handle them plus a clean room.

Comment: @user253751 you can only build an electron microscope in your garage for "much less than $1k" if you have $10k worth of stuff sitting in your garage that you're willing to count as "$0 because I wasn't using it anyway".